# Trouble removing rake 0.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having some trouble removing the rake gem version 0.9.  I managed to run `gem uninstall rake` and I believed this to have deleted it. However, going back to gem list it still showed that it still exists.

Running `gem env`:

```
GEM PATHS:
   /home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
   /home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global
```

I went into the `@global` directory and manually deleted it there, yet still it remains somewhere.  I can see it when I run `gem list`.  The 0.9 rake gem is causing problems for my Rails 3.0.7 application.

I ran `gem list -d rake`:

```
rake (0.9.0, 0.8.7)

Installed at 
(0.9.0): /home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global
(0.8.7): /home/sean/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
```

I don't see anything in the gems directory for ruby-1.9.2-p180@global

Comment: Are you using an RVM gemset in your app?

Comment: I think there is a file that contains the list of gems that are installed, and it doesn't get cleaned out correctly. Try doing a `grep -ci rake | grep -v :0$` and look at the files containing references to it. One is just a list. Remove `rake` from the list and you should be good. I can't remember the file to check for - it's been several weeks, but I had to do it on several machines.

Answer (score 48):

You should run

```
rvm use @global && gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.0  
rvm use @ && gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.0
```

to correctly remove rake 0.9.0 from rvm

Comment: `rvm use @global && gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.0` worked like a charm for me. Thanks!

Comment: `rvm use @ && gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.2` was the one for me... but that did the trick!  Thanks!

Comment: @Alexey I get `rake (10.1.0, 0.9.6)` when running `ruby -S gem list` but cannot `gem uninstall rake -v 0.9.6` as it says `ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError) gem "rake" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem` Any hint? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Steven, I have the same versions installed and get the same error. (gem list -d shows: Installed at (10.1.0): .rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global
                 (0.9.6, default): .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
)

Comment: @Steven, Using the `--backtrace` I figured out where the error was coming from (`.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/uninstaller.rb:107`). That led me to look for a default dir, which I found at `.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/specifications/default`. I ended up just manually deleting the files with `rm -r .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-0.9.6/ .rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/specifications/default/rake-0.9.6.gemspec`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100496/uninstalling-all-gems-ruby-2-0-0 also had some ideas.

Comment: @TylerRick I am currently not trouble shooting on this any more as there are more urgent things at the moment. Will be back as soon as time's come to deal with this problem again. Thanks already for the approach!

Comment: @Steven, no problem, I was just posting my solution in the hopes that it might help someone somewhere...

Answer (score 3):

In terminal type in: `gem uninstall rake`, then select version 0.9.0 when prompted.

Then modify your Gemfile within your Rails application:

```
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
```

Then in terminal run:

```
bundle install
```

These steps should fix the problems you are having. Upgrade to rake again when you upgrade to rails 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using rvm you get rake 0.9 installed "for free" in the global gemset which makes it hard (impossible?) to uninstall properly. `gem uninstall rake` is successful but doesn't  actually remove rake 0.9. I had to do it manually for both REE and 1.9.2.

I edited the rake executable script (find with `which rake`) and added a:

```
puts "Gem.bin_path: #{Gem.bin_path('rake', 'rake', version)}
```

...before the last line. This prints (on my system):
   Gem.bin_path: ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@global/gems/rake-0.9.0/bin/rake

To remove 0.9 cd into ~/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03 and manually delete all rake-0.9 files (gems, specifications are the ones that count I believe).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same problem (needed rake 0.8.7 but got 0.9.0 "for free" with rvm). Initially `gem list -d rake` gave the following output:

```
rake (0.9.0, 0.8.7)
  Installed at (0.9.0): ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global
               (0.8.7): ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_gemset
```

Switching to the global gemset with `rvm use @global` gave me this output:

```
rake (0.9.0)
  Installed at: ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global
```

So I just did `gem uninstall rake`. Now, switching back to my gemset with `rvm use @my_gemset` the correct version of rake (0.8.7) is being used.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bundler, you should read this [excellent article by Yehuda Katz](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/). Following his instructions means you don't have to uninstall rake 0.9.0. Try following command:

```
bundle exec rake --version
```

Prepending `bundle exec` will make sure that only the correct version of the rake is loaded, regardless of others you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the 'gem cleanup' script ?

Comment: I tried 'gem cleanup' and it still appears in 'gem list'.  But I don't see it in the gem path directories.

Comment: Only one version of ruby installed?

Comment: I inserted this into my rakefile above the load_tasks line:

Whatever::Application.send :include, ::Rake::DSL if defined?(::Rake::DSL)

So it looks like the rails app works now using rake 0.9.