# Uninstalling all gems Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-2.0

It seems that ruby 2.0.0 has added "default" gems to the mix and makes them non removable by gem uninstall.

How can you remove all non default gems?

Comment: Can you provide example of gems & how you installed Ruby 2.0 (manually? `rvm`?)

Comment: I used rbenv to install ruby 2.0.0-p0. Gems that are "default" for me at least are: bigdecimal 1.2.0, io-console 0.4.2, json 1.7.7, minitest 4.3.2, psych 2.0.0, rake 0.9.6, rdoc 4.0.0, test-unit 2.0.0.0. `gem uninstall json` errors with  gem "json" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. I never delete gems, not sure one would. Why do you need anything else than `gem cleanup`?

Comment: Sometimes I just want to get rid of things. Cleanup is probably what most people need most of the time. There are times however I want to get rid of all gems to test bash scripts that need to install things like gems.

Comment: `rvm` has gemsets, not sure about `rbenv`

Comment: I'm working with a system atm that has ruby without `rvm` or `rbenv`. But I agree if I has `rvm` a simple `rvm gemset empty` would do :)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I used this one line script.

```
for i in `gem list --no-versions`; do gem uninstall -aIx $i; done
```

It ignores default gem errors and just proceeds. Simple and self-evident.

Comment: That's a simpler solution for this problem, assuming rubygems continues to work this way :)

Comment: Nice work! You don't see a lot of terse shell commands posted using a loop.

Comment: Does not work. still get 'cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem' errors.

Comment: @Nippysaurus It's normal. You can just ignore it. If you mean the command stops after the first error, type `set +e` and try again.

Comment: @ihji would know if this works `gem list --no-version | awk 'NR>1{ print $(NF-1) }' | xargs gem 2>/dev/null uninstall -aIx` it doesn't error but it also doesn't uninstall the gems. I assume the command still stops executing when error occurs (even if it gets redirected)

Comment: If using zsh, you can be even shorter (only in the cli, not as a script), `for i in $(gem list --no-versions); gem uninstall -aIx $i`.

Answer (score 13):

First, go to the gems directory
Like ../ruby/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/specifications
You will find a directory named **default**, which including all the default gems shipped with ruby 2.0

Move all the ***.gemspec** stored in **default** dir to **specifications** dir and remove the empty **default** dir.

Then you can do whatever you want like old days.:-)

Comment: What is the specification directory used for now? It's in the load path I assume?

Comment: This worked for me.
The "solutions" in other SO questions, github & even the ruby gem docs did not work.

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a script in ruby to remove all non default gems.

https://gist.github.com/nixpulvis/5042764

This is needed now because unlike before 2.0.0 some gems are labeled "default" with the installation of ruby, and cannot be uninstalled with `gem uninstall`. This makes the previously popular methods for deleting all gems not work.

For reference here it is.
`gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall`

Comment: The supplied link no longer exists. "OH NOES, 404". Is there somewhere else this script exists, or is the "for reference" line the entire script?

Comment: Thanks. I changed my username. The URL is fixed.

Comment: this crashes for default gems

Comment: this doesn't work for cases where there are multiple versions for any specific gem

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet found a better answer than to exclude the "default" gems:

```
/usr/local/bin/gem list --no-versions | \
grep -v -E "(bigdecimal|io-console|json|minitest|psych|rake|rdoc|test-unit)" | \
xargs --no-run-if-empty /usr/local/bin/gem uninstall --executables --user-install --all --force
```

Comment: This code is assuming you installed ruby 2.0 from source on Linux.