# Unable to uninstall bundler 1.17.3

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

My current bundler version appears to be 1.17.3. I actually need 1.17.2 for my latest work, but I am unable to uninstall 1.17.3.

If I run `gem uninstall bundler` the command exits with no output. The command `gem info bundler` always shows version 1.17.3.

```
$ gem uninstall bundler
$ gem info bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
... yada yada yada ...
bundler (1.17.3)
    Installed at (default): /Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
```

If I install the bundler version I need, I get both versions installed, but the 1.17.3 version runs by default.

```
$ gem install bundler -v 1.17.2
Fetching bundler-1.17.2.gem
Successfully installed bundler-1.17.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.17.2
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.17.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
$ gem info bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
... yada yada yada ...    
bundler (1.17.3, 1.17.2)
    Installed at (1.17.3, default): /Users/disaacs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
                 (1.17.2): /Users/disaacs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3

    The best way to manage your application's dependencies
$ bundle --version
Bundler version 1.17.3
```

Any suggestions about how I can get rid of bundler 1.17.3?

My environment is a MacBook running 10.14.5 (Mojave), with ruby 2.5.3 installed via rvm.

```
$ rvm list
=* ruby-2.5.3 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Comment: Have you tried `gem install --default -v1.17.2 bundler`? Also, when you run `which gem` and `which bundler` do they show the rvm shim paths?

Comment: After running `gem install -default -v 1.17.2 bundler` I now have 2 default versions of bundler installed, and I can't uninstall either of them :( Also, the 1.17.3 version is still taking precedence.

Comment: `which gem` returns `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/gem`, `which bundle` returns `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/bundle`

Comment: I ran into something similar a few months back. I ended up deleting the default version following instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46691098/2892779), then re-installing with the --default flag again (only the one I wanted)

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work for me. It still won't uninstall the 1.17.3 bundler (though 1.17.3 is not longer marked as default). I was able to install 1.17.2 as default, but when I run bundler I am still getting version 1.17.3.

Comment: Have you tried re-shimming?  In asdf (plugin manager I use) it's just calling `asdf reshim ruby`, maybe `rvm reshim`? Also, I'd shut your terminal window down & re-open it to make sure there's not some kind of artifact leftover from something else affecting it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195205/discussion-between-jay-dorsey-and-dave-isaacs).

Answer (score 4):

In short, try navigate to a location except where your rails project is, and run `gem uninstall bundler` again.

---

MacOS 10.15.2, Ruby 2.6.5 and RubyGems 3.0.3

I was trying to uninstall bundler 2.1.4, and my default bundler is 1.17.2

```
$ gem list | grep "bundle"
bundler (2.1.4, default: 1.17.2)
```

And I tried

```
$ gem uninstall bundler -v 2.1.4
Gem 'bundler' is not installed
```

And also

```
$ gem uninstall bundler
```

just output nothing.

And finally I cd to another folder and run uninstall again and it worked.

Comment: Needs more upvotes. Only solution that worked.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that RubyGems 3.0.4 includes bundler 1.17.3, and this was overriding any earlier version of bundler I tried to install. I fixed the issue by downgrading my RubyGems to version 2.7.6.

```
$ gem update --system 2.7.6
```

Answer (score 2):

had same issue, use below process to uninstall it

```
1. $ rvm gemset use global
2. $ sudo gem uninstall bundler -v 1.17.3
3. $ gem install bundler -v 1.17.2
```