# How can I change the default minitest version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, minitest

After install ruby 2.1.2 on my Macbook Pro, I found the default minitest version is `4.7.5`, I do `sodo gem install minitest` to install minitest `5.4.2`, but the default gem is `4.7.5` yet.  I also do `gem cleanup`,that didn't remove the old version.I had try `gem uninstall minitest -v 4.7.5` and got

`RROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "minitest" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem`

So how can I change the default gem to version 5.4.2 and remove the old one? 
If I don't change this, I have to write  `class AbcTest < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase` not `class AbcTest < Minitest::Test` in my test. Or modify Gemfile everytime I create a new project.

PS:

**Ruby version:** `ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]`

**gem list minitest -d**

`minitest (5.4.2, 4.7.5)
    Author: Ryan Davis
    Homepage: https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest
    License: MIT
    Installed at (5.4.2): /Users/xxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
                 (4.7.5, default): /Users/xxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
    minitest provides a complete suite of testing facilities supporting
    TDD, BDD, mocking, and benchmarking`

Comment: Addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945110/how-can-i-remove-a-default-gem-want-to-uninstall-a-gem-1-7-7-version-of-json and further here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15133988/2117020. Not sure if you actually need to delete it, though. Output `Minitest::VERSION` in your test script. Most probably it is already 5.4.2.

Comment: @moonfly Both can't work and the output is 4.7.5

Comment: `Minitest::VERSION` doesn't work with older versions of Minitest, such as 4.3. However, `MiniTest::Unit::VERSION` does.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for uninstalling the older version:

```
gem uninstall minitest -v 4.7.5
```

Refer [Ruby Gems guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/)

Comment: I had try this and got```ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "minitest" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: "[How to make rake test not use the default minitest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29736396/how-to-make-rake-test-not-use-the-default-minitest/29805290#29805290)".

You can delete the `~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/` directory. Your more recent `minitest` gem will then be used automatically.