# How to make rake test not use the default minitest?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, minitest

I am following along the [Make your own Gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem) Guide from RubyGems. Executing the `rake test` instructions fails as follows:

```
> rake test
~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/unit.rb:26:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant MiniTest::Test (NameError)
<rest of output truncated>
```

I figured that it is because the minitest version being used is `4.7.5` and not `5.6.0` (or any of the 5.0.0 series that is needed to have `MiniTest::Test` be valid). So I installed `minitest 5.6.0` and now I have both versions of `minitest`. However `rake test` will still only use the `4.7.5` version.

How do I make it so that running `rake test` uses the right `minitest` within the setting of the Guide?

Using ruby directly works:

```
 > ruby -Ilib test/test_hola.rb
 Run options: --seed 48777

 # Running:

 ...

 Finished in 0.002862s, 1048.3550 runs/s, 1048.3550 assertions/s.

 3 runs, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Deleting minitest 4.7.5 is nigh impossible ;).

**Setup**

- Ruby 2.1.2 under rbenv 0.4.0-129-g7e0e85b
- rake (10.1.0)
- minitest (5.6.0, 4.7.5)
- Ubuntu 14.04

**Edit**

Adding `gem "minitest"` in `Rakefile` and/or `test_hola.rb` does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used was to delete the old minitest directory located at:
`~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/`.

Indeed, despite `gem list minitest -d` returning:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

minitest (5.6.0, 4.7.5)
    Author: Ryan Davis
    Homepage: https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest
    License: MIT
    Installed at (5.6.0): ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
                 (4.7.5, default): ~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0

minitest provides a complete suite of testing facilities supporting
TDD, BDD, mocking, and benchmarking
```

the `default minitest` location was actually `~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/minitest/`. The reported location for the newer `minitest` (`5.6.0` in this case) is correct.

Answer (score -1):

And the following line to your Rakefile:

```
gem "minitest"
```

Comment: Adding gem "minitest" in the Rakefile or the test file does not help. I still get the same error.