# Gem dependencies incompatibality during upgrade of rails 4.2.10 to rails 5.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler, gemfile

I am in a middle of a process of upgrading our rails 4 app.
Following the [rails upgrade guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html), I have updated current rails version in a `gemfile` replacing `4.2.10` with `5.0.0`.

But after running `bundle update rails`, I am getting many incompatibility issues even after running `4.2.10` (with `rails 4.2.10`) which should update all gems to the latest version.

Following are the compatibility errors I am getting after running `bundle update rails` with `rails 5.0.0` in a gemfile:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    active_link_to was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
      actionpack

    active_model_serializers was resolved to 0.10.2, which depends on
      actionpack (< 6, >= 4.1)

    inherited_resources was resolved to 1.6.0, which depends on
      actionpack (< 5, >= 3.2)

    inherited_resources was resolved to 1.6.0, which depends on
      actionpack (< 5, >= 3.2)

    kaminari was resolved to 0.17.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0)

    rspec-rails (= 3.6.0) was resolved to 3.6.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
```

Comment: can you copy your gemfile pls ?

Comment: I don't think there's a need to paste a whole gemfile here and make the question further bulky as I have pasted whatever errors I am getting while upgrading the rails version using `bundle update rails`.

I have specified `gem rails, '5.0.0'` in my gemfile.

Comment: 2 things that could help if not already done in your gemfile : mention the Ruby version on top of it (in case it defaults to an old incompatible Ruby version) and remove versioning of all other gems than Rails (which is versionned to 5.0.0)

Comment: my ruby version is `2.4.2` which is the latest stable release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after many trials & testing, I was able to run bundle install. Listing steps that I tried-

**1. Create a new demo rails app using `rails new` with `rails 5`**.

**2. Remove existing `Gemfile.lock`**.

**3. Remove all current gems**: (I used ***for i in `gem list --no-versions`; do gem uninstall -aIx $i; done*** command referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15133988/4675524).)

**4. Replace existing `Gemfile` with the new one that was generated from creating new `rails 5` app**. (assuming you'll be having a backup copy of existing `Gemfile`.)

**5. Copy individual gems from old file to the new one**.

**6. Run `bundle install`**. (You should be having a :) after this execution.)

**7. Run `rails app:update` to continue with the upgrade process**.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question?

Before update a gem you have to check if your project code and dependencies are ready for this changes, not an easy process if this is a big app.

#### 1. Come back to de rails version you had.

`gem install <gem> -v=<version>`

e.g.

`gem install rails -v=4.2`

This way your rails app should use the version you want.

#### 2. Update the rest of the gems... (not recommend it if you are not sure about the new releases)

Check your Gemfile.lock:

`bundle update`

Or delete your Gemfile.lock (it will be rebuild automatically when you try to start your rails app).

Comment: I am upgrading `rails 4.2` to `rails 5`.
So I have updated all gems in my gemfile to the latest version to ensure that all are compatible with `rails 5` (will resolve any other code dependencies on gem version once the rails version is upgraded).

Comment: Try to **update/install actionpack** `budle install actionpack -v=5.0.0`. Then you will resolve this issue but probably, you will have other gem dependencies errors.

Comment: Yes. I even uninstalled all of the gems for `ruby 2.4.2`.